# How to find the next div down the dom by class

Tags: jquery

I'd like to append a `hello` paragraph to the first next div with class `placeholder`. 
There is a `ul` between `Reply` and the target div and there are several `placeholder` classes on the page.

The problem is that I can not traverse the dom and find the very next `placeholder`. How can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".replyit").click(function() {
  let hello = '<p>hello</p>'
    
   $(this).closest(".treply").next().find(".placeholder").append(hello);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row treply">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <p>Awsome post</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a class="replyit" href="#">Reply</a>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class="likep" name="123" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="afewf">
      <input class="pid" type="hidden" name="pid" value="123">

    </form>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: $(this).closest(".treply").siblings(".placeholder").append(hello); find looks inside an element so it will never find .placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can call `nextAll()`, along with `:first`, to get the closest following sibling `.placeholder` to the clicked `.treply`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".replyit").click(function() {
    let hello = '<p>hello</p>'
    $(this).closest(".treply").nextAll('.placeholder:first').append(hello);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row treply">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <p>Awsome post #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a class="replyit" href="#">Reply</a>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class="likep" name="123" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="afewf">
      <input class="pid" type="hidden" name="pid" value="123">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="placeholder"></div>

<div class="row treply">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <p>Awsome post #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a class="replyit" href="#">Reply</a>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class="likep" name="123" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="afewf">
      <input class="pid" type="hidden" name="pid" value="123">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).closest(".treply").next()` gives you the next `ul` element. The placeholder is after that, not inside. You can't get it with find.

If you're certain you'll have `ul` element between reply and target div then you can just call the `.next()` chain twice and get to `div.placeholder`.

Try this

`$(this).closest(".treply").next().next().append(hello);`

You can also use this

`$(this).closest(".treply").siblings('.placeholder:eq(0)')`

This will give you the first element with class `placeholder` after reply div block.